# Why does Windows' performance degrade over time even when it isn't used?

Tags: windows, performance

I know that similar questions have been asked before (like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/128323/why-does-microsoft-windows-performance-appear-to-degrade-over-time) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/199337/what-are-the-technical-reasons-for-the-gradual-degrade-in-performance-of-compute)), but none of them answer my question. My problem is, as stated in the title, that when Windows isn't in use (some months) its performance degrades. (Boot time goes from ½ minute to 2 minutes) If I boot Windows every day for a week, the boot time shrinks, but I have disabled defragmentation.

The other answers indicate that it might be fragmentation or bit rot. I know for sure that i can't be fragmentation since the hard drive is not use when not booting Windows (except for benchmarking from Linux). However, when benchmarking the drive under Linux (always booting from a separate drive), the drive's performance doesn't drop over time.

Edit:
The computer I described in the question runs Windows 8, however I've also experienced this on Windows 7.

Comment: This behavior is different per windows version. Can you edit your post and clarify which version of windows you are talking about?

Comment: So you're also using the same drive for a Linux install that you DO use regularly?

Comment: @techie007 No, I use one physical drive for Windows, and another for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Windows uses something called **prefetch** which is basically a cache of the process you use the most. If it were to expire, Windows would have to build it from scratch again.

I personally haven't experienced something like this, I use Windows roughtly once every month and it takes the same time to boot always and the performance once it's loaded is the same (it's Windows 8.1 though, I don't exactly know the inner workings of it or prefetch).

Comment: prefetch is not applicable if you are using memory drives of course as it is not necessary.  The windows installer upon detecting this will disable this feature.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with *memory drives*?

Comment: I mean the SSD drives....

Comment: The OP didn't state that he had any SSD's. Otherwise maybe he'd not even be complaining about performance.